# Why doesn't console.table() work for all objects/arrays?

Tags: javascript, browser

Why doesn't `console.table()` work for all objects / arrays?

With some data I get a nicely formatted table in the developer console. With other data I get nothing... not even an error message.

I just learned about `console.table()` while going through the challenges of [#Javascript30](https://javascript30.com). The presenter used `console.table()` for some of the output, but not all, and he didn't explain why. I tried to use it for all of the (array or object) output and saw why... it doesn't work.

Here's an example of one that doesn't work.

```js
const data = ['car', 'car', 'truck', 'truck', 'bike', 'walk', 'car', 'van', 'bike', 'walk', 'car', 'van', 'car', 'truck' ];

const transportation = data.reduce((counters, item) => {
  if (!counters[item]) counters[item] = 0;
  counters[item]++;
  return counters;
}, {});
console.log('transportation table');
console.table(transportation);

console.log('transportation log');
console.log(transportation);
```

```html
<h1>Look at the console!</h1>
```

I expected `console.table()` to return something like this:

[image: MDN Example]

... except that the (index) column would contain car, truck, bike, etc. and the Values column would contain the count.

### Update

Apparently `console.table()` doesn't work with SO's code snippets... which in this case means that it works exactly the same as it does on browsers :P So, I posted an example of the problem at CodePen: http://codepen.io/VAggrippino/pen/qRraEP

This was the 4th challenge, [Array Cardio 1](https://javascript30.com/account/access/587fde5d58e94708b4e66721/view/3dabaeb847) for those of you following along.

I realize that this isn't strictly a programming / JavaScript question since the console is a feature of the browser, not the language or the DOM. I believe it's relevant because the browser is an essential tool that all web developers use and every major browser supports it.

Comment: By the way, `console.table` does not work in snippets. See http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/340915/console-group-not-working-in-js-snippets.

Comment: @torazaburo In that case, for my specific example, it works exactly the same as it does in Chrome :D

Comment: More of a general note: for me it doesn't display a table while the DevConsole isn't open. So if I have something running in the background and then open the DevConsole, there's no table, only the array shows up. To be clear, it's not necessary to type the command into the console, the console has to be open while the code executes.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

I'm currently working on the same exercise for JS30 and encountered the same problem as you, which led me here.

I consulted the [console.table() page on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Console/table), and after doing some testing it appears that this might be a Chrome issue.

From my limited testing, it seems like Chrome doesn't output a table for collections of primitive types (array of strings, single object), only collections of compound types (array of arrays/objects, object whose properties are objects).

This doesn't work:

```
console.table(['1','2','3']);
```

But this does:

```
console.table([['1','2','3']]);
```

I also tested on Canary, but had the same results.

However on Firefox, `console.table()` seems to work correctly. The MDN examples of collections of primitive types worked on Firefox, but not on Chrome.

To have an output on Chrome for your example, what you could do is put the transportation variable inside its own array, so that Chrome will print the table.

```
console.table([transportation]);
```

Comment: I tried to implement it as;
console.table(arr_cars, ['0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7']); but it seems that browser shows only first 0-5 columns, even rest of columns are enough small (narrow) to be showed too (Firefox). I gave up.

Comment: I ended up with `console.table({...fifteen})` (instead of `console.table(fifteen)`)

Comment: I think it works with primitive data types as well, the example that you have provided under "This doesn't work", seems to work, it outputs it in a table. Funny enough, the compound example that you have given doesn't work in a table formate.

Answer (score 1):

In theory console.table() prints tables (2 dimensions) not arrays (1 dimension) so the outer array is a list of rows (like `<tr>`s) and each inner array contains the values for each column for that row (like `<td>`s).

Answer (score -2):

Just open new tab and open your console and type console.table([['1','2','3']]); and run it and then try running your file and see if that works or not. but for me it worked!